# PowerBI fixing custom start date for Date Range slicer

Tags: powerbi, date-range, slicers

In PowerBI while using DateRange slicer is it possible to fix the Start Date as 01-06-2022 and End Date as today's date and still we can select older dates from the Date Range selector so that we can list records available for older dates.

I did try to put static start date for date range but that disables the older dates for which there are records available.

Comment: Define your range in a measure directly! then you can set the requested limits! At the end, It will get those dates directly from your date tables which also contain full range of dates(including old)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a measure like this if you prefer:

Creating a date table in your model is considered as one of the best BI practices. It helps sorting, filtering, and grouping in your analytics calculations!

```
Your_Measure =
CALCULATE (
    [Total_Sales],
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Calendar[Date] ),
        Calendar[Date] >= DATE ( 2022, 06, 01 )
            && Calendar[Date] <= TODAY ()
    )
)
```

Update requested from @Mano

Here is the Calendar table you need to create! Do not put today() function here! This is a dimensional date table in a star-schema data model. When you write your measure, You need to integrate it there. I will write it for you now!

```
Calendar =
VAR _cal =
    CALENDAR (
        DATE ( YEAR ( MIN ( email_notification_info[email_notification_sent] ) ), 01, 01 ),
        DATE ( YEAR ( MAX ( email_notification_info[email_notification_sent] ) ), 12, 31 )
    )
VAR _result =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        _cal,
        "Year", YEAR([DateColumn]),
        "MonthNumber", MONTH([DateColumn]),
        "MonthName", FORMAT ( [DateColumn], "mmmm" ),
        "Period", FORMAT ( [DateColumn], "YYYY-MM" )
    )
RETURN
    _result
```

Now Your final measure is almost the same as above:

```
    Your_Measure =
VAR your_variable =
    DATE ( 2022, 06, 01 ) -- Enter any beginning date here!
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        [your_measure here],
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Calendar[DateColumn] ),
            Calendar[DateColumn] >= your_variable
                && Calendar[DateColumn] <= TODAY ()
        )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Comment: I have created a measure as mentioned below. Can you please guide me how can I put the condition for start date keeping older date enabled.

Calendar = 

var _cal = CALENDAR(MIN(email_notification_info[email_notification_sent], TODAY())
var _result = 

ADDCOLUMNS(

 _cal,

 .....

      .....

)
return

_result

Comment: @Mano I updated my post with your request! Please check it there!

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response. Let me try the above solution.